# How do I get sound to work out of fluid.app windows?

Tags: macos, fluid.app

This used to work; I don't know when it stopped; but I now can't get sounds out of any apps I build with fluid.app (the one I try to use most is for player.siriusxm.com). I'm not sure it's specific to fluid.app as I tried an alternative "create an app out of a webpage" solution and it had the same problem. Separate safari windows work fine. Running Ventura 13.4 on a M1 MacBook Pro.